# Print an R dataframe with format in databricks

Tags: r, dataframe, databricks

I have the following code in R:

(taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html)

```
library(formattable)

sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                        style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 0, "green", 
                                                         ifelse(x < 0, "red", "black"))) )

products <- data.frame(id = 1:5, 
                   price = c(10, 15, 12, 8, 9),
                   rating = c(5, 4, 4, 3, 4),
                   market_share = percent(c(0.1, 0.12, 0.05, 0.03, 0.14)),
                   revenue = accounting(c(55000, 36400, 12000, -25000, 98100), digits = 0L),
                   profit = accounting(c(25300, 11500, -8200, -46000, 65000)))



formattable(products, list(
  price = color_tile("transparent", "lightpink"),
  rating = color_bar("lightgreen"),
  market_share = color_bar("lightblue"),
  revenue = sign_formatter,
  profit = sign_formatter) )
```

That prints the following table

[image]

How can I replicate this in databricks, or something similar

Answer (score 0):

For now this it´s not very posible in databricks, the way to go is to use the rstudio interface that they have, but I think it´s paid, for now thats all I have